# Should the correlation check should happen at the start of the receive chain?

Tags: digital-communications

Should the correlation check should happen at the start of the receive chain.
does it act like a start of burst data? But does phase and freq offset has any effect on this?
or should it happen at bit level after the data has been recovered as the freq and phase will be already recovered?

Comment: which receive chain? correlation check, which check? We'll need a lot more information on the thing you're looking at and the problem you're solving before these questions make sense. I think you assume communication systems are all alike, and they are to some degree, but they're not as much as you seem to imply. You'll have to explain what kind of receiver you're building.

Comment: **Also: You've received 7 answers already, and accepted or voted on none**. A lot of these answers were pretty high-effort, and you'll need to engange with the community if you want it to persist in offering answers.